# Why does the subclass access the parent's field but not their own in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

```java
class Parent {
    int money = 10000;
    int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int money = 5000;
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child c = new Child();
        System.out.println(c.getMoney());
    }
}
```

The output is 10000. Also if I edit the getter to say `return this.money` I get the same result.

So why does Java take superclass's field but not the caller's (`Child`). I know Python more and it shouldn't be like this in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override variables in Java. The method is in the `Parent` class which means that `money` will access the variable in the `Parent` class also.

The thing that can be done in Java is *hiding* as opposed to overriding. If you declared the getter in the `Child` class then it would print `5000` as the `Parent` `money` variable has been hidden.

---

To address your edit about using `this`, it won't change anything. By referencing a variable in a class, you're already implicitly referring to `this`.

Comment: if you show getter code, it would be perfect

Comment: You mean for an example in hiding?

Comment: so, you mean every subclass have their own getter? it doesn't seem efficient

Comment: yes, hiding. I don't understan at all, so need code example

Comment: No that's definitely not what I mean. There's only one and that's in the `Parent` class, which is why returning `money` will return the variable in the `Parent` class.

Comment: For an example of hiding, move the getter to the child class.